# 30 thousand dropped packets in 6 days, is that yet normal or is it time to be worried?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

My home laptop runs usually 24/7, as I don't like to shut it down, I now looked at the result of:

```
sudo iptables --list --verbose --line-numbers
```

which showed me, in my opinion, excessive amount of dropped packets, see below:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 29042 packets, 11M bytes)
```

```
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
2        8   544 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
3    25761 4073K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
4     373K  533M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

**in up time of 6 days.** That makes an average of about 5 000 dropped packets in a single day.

---

**System**: Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64-bit

**Kernel**: 4.13.0-43-generic

**Firewall**: `iptables` version 1.6.0

---

As I don't understand networking, may I ask if such amount in that time period is rather normal and there is no reason to be worried?

Or is it rather too much, and I should investigate?

Comment: Why do you run it 24/7? You can suspend it. This is such a waste of electricity.

Comment: @daka I have Ultra Low Energy consuming CPU i7-4510U, so I doubt I waste much.

Comment: But why is my question, while you are a sleep, what use is it keeping it on?

Comment: @daka My mother uses the laptop, so I don't know. She just likes it so, I guess. But I find it unnecessary to explain it. Let's leave it at that.

Comment: My apologies for going off course here, but I get annoyed when I hear things like this, I'm all for looking after mother earth and using the finite resource we have wisely. Might I suggest investing in a raspberry pi for your mother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing there are not packets dropped by the Ethernet interface layer.

What you are seeing is statistics of the INPUT firewall/iptables queue, that by default is in DROP mode in your setup. So, all the rules that are not accepted and not matched by your INPUT chain firewall rules, go to the last DROP rule.

So ultimately, this means those counters are packets that are refused by your firewall processing whatever rules you created to enhance your security. The numbers seem perfectly normal for a system directly connected to the Internet.

Comment: Anecdotal tale: I once got +200K  SSH bot probes on a single night on a single server.